# Script for taking SQL DUMP

Tags: shell, script, sql

I am writing the script for taking the sql dump & zipping it.

```
#!/bin/sh
DBUSERID="root"
DBPASSWORD="XXXXXXXX"
BACKUP_DIR="$HOME/daily_sql_backups"
DATE=`date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S`
cd $BACKUP_DIR
mysql -u$DBUSERID -p$DBPASSWORD  --socket=/data/mysql/mysql.sock -e 'show databases' | grep abcd >MICRO_SERVICES.txt

sed -e '/^abcd_prod$/d' MICRO_SERVICES.txt > MICRO_SERVICES_DB.txt 
cat MICRO_SERVICES_DB.txt | while read line
do
    DB=$line
    mysqldump --opt --user=${DBUSERID} --password=${DBPASSWORD} --socket=/data/mysql/mysql.sock ${DB} > $DB_$DATE.sql 2> "$DB"_"$DATE".err
    gzip $DB_$DATE.sql
    status=$?
    err=`cat "$DB"_"$DATE".err |wc -l`
    DATE_COMPLETED=$(date "+%F # %T")
    if [ $err -eq 0 -a $status -eq 0 ]
    then
       echo "$DATE_COMPLETED : DB backup success" >>/backup_logs/"$DB"_backup-$(date +%b-%Y).txt
       echo "$DATE_COMPLETED : DB backup success"
    else
       echo "$DATE_COMPLETED : DB backup FAILURE" >> /backup_logs/"$DB"_backup-error-$(date +%b-%Y).txt
       cat "$DB"_"$DATE".err >>/tmp/"$DB"_backup-error-$(date +%b-%Y).txt
       cat "$DB"_"$DATE".err |mail -s "$DB: dump failure" devops@xxxx.com
    fi
   sleep 1m
done
```

I am getting the error "gzip: /home/XXXXXX/daily_sql_backups/2017_12_07_14_28_02.sql.gz already exists; not overwritten"
And i am getting the error dump failure. Could someone please let me know where i am doing wrong

Comment: You could use `gzip -f`. That would force overwrite any existing data, but you need to make sure there really is no data there

Comment: Actually it worked when i used "$DB"_"$DATE".sql instead of $DB_$DATE.sql. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Run your script through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and it will give you some clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it worked when i used

```
"$DB"_"$DATE".sql
```

instead of

```
$DB_$DATE.sql.
```

Can someone explain why?